# How to prevent sending requests to RESTful API directly on a SPA project?

Tags: api, rest, security, single-page-application, csrf

I have a Single Page App application which is working based on RESTful APIs. Generally, all APIs have a route access which can be found while inspecting web application.
Although I have authentication mechanism based on user tokens, a hacker can find the API routes and use his given token to send many requests to APIs directly.
What is the best solution to prevent such behavior? I was thinking about CSRF, but as APIs are based on REST, and the project is a SPA, I think I should have another mechanism.
May you help me please?

Comment: You could add rate-limiting per API key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot authenticate the client application, it is not possible. If a user can send a request from an spa, because they have the credentials and the endpoints to send them to, they can use whatever client from Burp through ZAP or Postman to curl or whatever else to send the request.

Your API must be resilient, you should have rate limiting, user quotas, monitoring and secure operation practices in general on the server side based on your threat model to mitigate this risk.

In practice this might mean hosting the API in a way that's resilient to DoS on the network level, having a per-user request rate limit, identifying functionality that is a burden for the server for some reason (calls external services, sends email and so on) and protect/monitor those even more carefully. There is no one size fits all solution.